# Blazor WASM classes in css isolation not found

Tags: css, blazor

I have a blazor wasm application and I try to add a css file with css isolation. My File structure looks like this:

[image]

And my code in the Layout header is:

```
<Header Style="background: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5" Class="header-layout">
    <div class="header-logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="80" />
    </div>
    <div class="header-avatar">
        <Avatar Style="background-color: #87d068" Icon="user" />
    </div>
</Header>
```

And I have this Link in my index.html:

```
<link href="[Projectname].Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And the css code is:

```
.header-layout {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center
}

.header-logo {
    flex-grow: 0
}

.header-avatar {
    flex-shrink: 0
}
```

When I move the css to the app.css it is applied correctly. But when in the LayoutHeader.razor.css it doesn't do anything. The style.css is correctly resolved (or at least I don't see any errors on the console).
Cache is disabled and I tried reloading everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The probelm was two fold:

1. For some reason you cannot have only a Blazor Component in a razor.cs file. That way the attribute cannot be applied. So you would have to surround it with a `<div></div>`.
2. The `header-layout`, `header-logo` and `header-avatar` need to have a `::deep` in front of it, since technically they are in a child component.

Comment: This worked for me 100%.  I had a regular page where CSS isolation was working perfectly and then I had a razor component where I couldn't get it to work for the life of me.  When I surrounded it with a <div></div> tag, BAM!  Worked perfectly.  Thanks!